# Language change in the phone didn't affect the app - Android

Tags: android, localization, settings, android-resources

```
<resources>
    <string name="otpValidationMessage">Please enter the One Time Password\n and validate your phone number</string>

    <string name="firstName">First Name</string>
    <string name="lastName">Last Name</string>
    <string name="mobileNumber">Mobile Number</string>
    <string name="otpPassword">One Time Password</string>
    <string name="code">Code</string>
    <string name="resendOTp">Resend OTP</string>
```

I've changed the phone language, But I don't see the language change in my app. I have all my text in the String file but still, there is no change in the app.

Comment: Restart the activity

Comment: check if your app has fixed  typeface and size for text

Comment: Can u give  pass a screenShot for the structure of strings files ?

Comment: can you please post your manifest?

Comment: I've tried restarting but no change! @chetan

Comment: I haven't added any support to the manifest file @cjurjiu

Comment: What you mean by this "Please enter the One Time Password\n and validate your phone number" is that the one you need to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onCreate do this to change your language to arabi

```
myLocale = new Locale("ar");//"en" if you want english
Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
config.locale = myLocale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
your_text_view.setText(R.string.Name);
```

and in strings you create as res/values-ar/strings.xml

```
<string name="Name">Arabi</string>
```

and in strings you create as res/values-en/strings.xml

```
<string name="Name">English</string>
```

If you have any doubts comment down

Comment: But creating a file for all languages is hard! Is there a way that it changes the string dynamically to the system language  @GT

Comment: yeah ofcourse else how would phone get the translated language we have to mention it

Comment: Here in this code the texview has arabi if ar is set and english if en is set in mylocale respectively

Comment: I guess we cant get it done using manifest and if not added on onCreate it will take language from Phone Language